# How do I start two different Python scripts with rc.local?

Tags: raspbian, python, boot, script

I have two different Python scripts I'd like to run at start-up on my Raspberry Pi A+. Both work perfectly if I run them via `sudo python filename.py`. I can get the first one to run, but not the second one in the rc.local below. It doesn't matter if I switch them or not, only the first one runs, and only if I don't have `&` at the end.

Here is my /etc/rc.local:

(Notice the commented-out version - it doesn't work either; but the hardware clock does...)

```bsh
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi


python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/shutdown.py
python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/ZBA_Timelapse.py

###python /home/ZBA_Timelapse/shutdown.py &
###(sleep 30; python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/ZBA_Timelapse.py) &

echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1_new_device
sudo hwclock -s

exit 0
```

EDIT:

I tried appending `&` to the end of the line per SlySven's answer, but it still does nothing. Both Python scripts are infinite loop programs, so I thought I'd try another approach: a shell script. The newly tried rc.local:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

./home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/startup.sh
echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1_new_device
sudo hwclock -s

exit 0
```

startup.sh looks like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash/
sudo python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/shutdown.py &
sudo python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/ZBA_Timelapse.py &
```

After both of those were set, I used `sudo chmod +x /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/startup.sh` to make startup.sh executable and rebooted. After reboot I used `cd ZBA_Timelapse` and `./startup.sh` to successfully test the shell script. It worked great. Both Python scripts executed and worked like they should.

I still had no luck on auto-starting both Python scripts on boot. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you might wanna `&` at the end of each execution so that both can run in parallel, ie, instead of your current lines, use `python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/shutdown.py &
python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/ZBA_Timelapse.py &` Hope it helps. For more info on using `&` in linux, read this question (and answers of course :P) http://superuser.com/questions/152688/why-run-a-linux-shell-command-with

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work either (hence the commented out section in the rc.local).

Comment: If something mysteriously "doesn't run" from `rc.local`, you should log the output of the command to see what is happening; I usually do this with an explicit subshell so `(sudo foobar) &> /var/log/foobar &`.  Which version of Raspbian are you running, BTW?  If it is jessie I can give you an example of how to do this as a discrete service w/ systemd (which is sort of simpler than it is with sysv on wheezy).

Comment: I replaced `python /home/...` in the rc.local with `(python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/shutdown.py) &> /var/log/timelapse.log &` & `(sleep 30 && python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/ZBA_Timelapse.py) &> /var/log/timelapse.log &` The log file is empty after a reboot. And the python scripts still don't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, thanks everyone for the suggestions in the other answers, but this is how I got it to work: I added `python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/startup.py` to the rc.local, then I created a single python file that starts multiple python files in different threads.

This is what rc.local looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/startup.py

echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1_new_device
sudo hwclock -s

exit 0
```

This is what startup.py looks like:

```
import time
from threading
import os

def startprgm(i):
    print "Running thread %d" % i
    if (i == 0):
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Running: shutdown.py')
        os.system("sudo python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/shutdown.py")
    elif (i == 1):
        print('Running: ZBA_Timelapse.py')
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system("sudo python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/ZBA_Timelapse.py")
    else:
        pass

for i in range(2):
    t = threasding.Thread(target=startprgm, args=(i,))
    t.start()
```

Obviously, I could increase the number of programs running by increasing i and adding another elif... It's not particularly pretty, but it works.

Comment: If anyone has any suggestion for code cleanup, let me know. The full project can be found here: https://github.com/pyreflos/RasPi-Rattle

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi


python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/shutdown.py &
python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/ZBA_Timelapse.py &

echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1_new_device
sudo hwclock -s

exit 0
```

The commented out code with the sleep might work better as:

```bsh
python /home/ZBA_Timelapse/shutdown.py &
sleep 30 && python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/ZBA_Timelapse.py &
```

One point to note is "do either of the python scripts in `/home/ZBA_Timelapse/` take input from stdin"?  If so, they will stop when they get to that point, waiting in the background for input until they are brought back to the foreground - and as this is a non-interactive script run during multi-level startup - they will hang around for ever waiting for input that never comes...

Comment: I tried appending & to the end of the line, but it still does nothing. Both python scripts are infinite loop programs (basically While True), one of which has a GPIO interrupt. I'm not sure what a stdin condition is...

I also tried replacing the python calls to a shell script that executed both. The shell script work well when run directly, but does not auto-start on boot. What am I doing wrong here?

I also edit the question to show the shell script, but I can't figure out how to approve reviews...

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
nohup python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/shutdown.py >/dev/null 2>&1 &
nohup python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/ZBA_Timelapse.py >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This will pipe output to /dev/null (aka nowhere) and not create a nohup.out file.

Or you could try with "screen":

```
man screen
```

Your command should look like:

```
screen -d -m /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/ZBA_Timelapse.py
```

Comment: This did not work either. I don't seem to have screen. Can you point me towards it?

Comment: Are the scripts executable ? (Do a 'chmod +x 'on both files) also see if screen is in the repo maybe. Or try without the piping to dev null, just with nohup at the beginning  and the & at the end

Comment: I made the scripts executable, but to no avail. Which makes sense... they're written in python, not shell scripts. I installed screen, but haven't gotten a chance to dig through it yet.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

The environment variables inherited when init runs rc.local are different from the environment you have when you login.

This sounds like a candidate to be service, so learning about services would help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import os


def startprgm(i):
    print "Running thread %d" % i
    if (i == 0):
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Running: shutdown.py')
        os.system("sudo python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/shutdown.py")
    elif (i == 1):
        print('Running: ZBA_Timelapse.py')
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system("sudo python /home/pi/ZBA_Timelapse/ZBA_Timelapse.py")
    else:
        pass

for i in range(2):
    t = Thread(target=startprgm, args=(i,))
    t.start()
```